# How to gather all bundle.yaml of juju

Tags: juju

I want a dataset of application graphs for testing purposes of a mine recommender system approach.
I can't find something similar [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/)
Thus, I am trying to gather all bundles(=app graph in juju) yaml files for using them as a set of app graphs.
Is anybody there to know how I can get them all with one try?
In the next link you can see a bundle with its yaml files.
https://jujucharms.com/u/bigdata-charmers/apache-hadoop-spark-zeppelin/

Answer (score 1):

*Copying the contents of my email here too so people will find it more easily if they google it.*

I recently asked a similar question for a paper I've written
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju/2018-January/009845.html.

- Here is the documentation for the charm store api: https://github.com/juju/charmstore/blob/v5-unstable/docs/API.md
- URL to download the entire zip for a bundle: https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/bundle//archive
- URL to download a specific file of a bundle: https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/bundle//archive/bundle.yaml

If you want code, here is an Jupyter notebook I use to get metrics of charm and layer usage: https://github.com/IBCNServices/reactive-pattern-results/blob/master/reactive-usage-stats.ipynb. It should be easy to modify that code to pull info about the bundles.

- As an example; this is the URL to get all bundles in the Juju store: https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/list?type=bundle

Cleaning up the data will be the hard part probably, since there are a lot of unused/broken bundles in the store. I've used the downloads/month metric to figure out what charms are actually still used.

source: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju/2018-June/009977.html